# expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token ? error

Tags: c++, c

i searched and find some other questions like this. But i cant find the fail in my code.
Maybe someone find it?
This is/was c-code. but i had to rename it in .cpp and so i have no some errors:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/numa'
c++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/include/libxml2     -g -O2 -MT numabench.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/numabench.Tpo -c -o numabench.o numabench.cpp
numabench.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
numabench.cpp:176:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
numabench.cpp:176:31: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
numabench.cpp:192:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
```

And this is the method of the numabench.cpp

What is there missing. Anyone an idea?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    setup_t* setup = (setup_t){
          .regions = (memory_regions_t){ .count = 0, .regions = NULL }
    };

    assert(argc == 2);
    parse_setup_file(&setup, argv[1]);
    printf("<?xml version='1.0'?>\n\n");
    printf("<numabench-result>\n\n");
    iterate_params(&setup, 0);
    printf("</numabench-result>\n");
    mainPCM();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I think this is your problem: `};` remove the `;` does that do the trick?

Comment: The designated initialisers for `setup` are C (C99) syntax. You seem to compile as C++. (As far as I know, C++ doesn't have designated initialisers, but I'm not exactly a C++ expert.)

Comment: Try to rename that file to numabench.c instead of .cpp

Comment: In other words, C != C++. In general tag only the language you are compiling.

Comment: @crashmstr He did. This used to be compiled as C code.

Comment: I try to remove the    ; but it does not work also.

Comment: is the statement 
    .regions = (memory_regions_t) { .count = 0, .regions = NULL }
not important? i have to remove it??!

Comment: @nikomad it is not that they are not imporatnt, that's not a valid C++ code and you are compiling it in C++

Comment: Where did you get that file from? Why does it have .cpp extension?

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses two C features, that C++ doesn't recognise: *compound literals* that allow you to specify values for compound data structures (arrays and structs) outside initialisation and *designated initialisers* that allow you to initialise individual fields of structures or individual array entries.

I assume that `setup_t` is a typedef to a structure. Your code:

```
setup_t* setup = (setup_t){
      .regions = (memory_regions_t){ .count = 0, .regions = NULL }
};
```

does not compile in C. The compiler wants either

```
setup_t *setup = (setup_t[]) {{ .regions = ... }};
```

or

```
setup_t *setup = &(setup_t) { .regions = ... };
```

Otherwise you have incompatible types in initialisation, namely `setup_t *` and `setup_t`.

You can get around the compound literal by specifying an instance of `setup_t` and making `setup` a pointer to that:

```
setup_t data = { .regions = ... };
setup_t *setup = &data;
```

You can get around the designated initialisers by either specifying the fields in order as in C89 or by creating an instance that is initialised to all zeros and then assigning values to the fields you want to initialise.

In your case, all initialised values are zero. Initialising at least one field ensures that all subsequent fields are also initalised with zero or null values. You could try:

```
setup_t data = {0};
setup_t *setup = &data;
```

Or, it the first field of `setup_t` is a structure, for example, `regions`:

```
setup_t data = {{0}};
setup_t *setup = &data;
```

I've tried this with a (made-up) struct and It seems to work in C++.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Yes, of course, it's a literal for compunds. (I must admit that I often mix up designated initialisers and compound literals, although the concepts are straightforward.) Thanks for pointing that out, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should actually be getting a different set of errors then what you've shown above:

```
[12:33am][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] c++ foo.cc 
foo.cc:3:5: error: unknown type name 'setup_t'
    setup_t* setup = (setup_t){
    ^
foo.cc:3:23: error: use of undeclared identifier 'setup_t'; did you mean
      'setup'?
    setup_t* setup = (setup_t){
                      ^~~~~~~
                      setup
foo.cc:3:14: note: 'setup' declared here
    setup_t* setup = (setup_t){
             ^
foo.cc:7:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'assert'
    assert(argc == 2);
    ^
foo.cc:9:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'printf'
    printf("<?xml version='1.0'?>\n\n");
    ^
foo.cc:10:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'printf'
    printf("<numabench-result>\n\n");
    ^
foo.cc:12:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'printf'
    printf("</numabench-result>\n");
    ^
foo.cc:13:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mainPCM'
    mainPCM();
    ^
foo.cc:14:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EXIT_SUCCESS'
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
           ^
8 errors generated.
```

Notably, you are missing some `#include <...>` statements, the declaration for `setup_t`, and the declaration for `mainPCM()`.

Comment: That's not really an answer, is it? The OP's code is just an excerpt that shows the part of the code where the error is indicated. (The line with `setup_t` is line 176 in OP's error message.)

Comment: @MOehm: Not to me. The code shown should be producing something like the errors here. To fix those errors, they should include `cstdlib`, `cstdio`, `cassert` and define those two functions. Are we supposed to guess what the code is instead of using the code that nikomad showed us?